# accessing MATLAB from a different user account

Tags: matlab, unix, user-permissions

I have MATLAB installed in my home directory on a linux machine which has multiple users. I want to allow one specific user and not all users to be able to run MATLAB from his user login. How can I do this?

I believe that one way to do this is to change the permissions of  my home directory so that it's accessible to all users but I don't want to do that.

Comment: This isn't off topic. UNIX questions most certainly "...relate to programming..." -there are entire sections of Stack Overflow devoted to such things. This question just needed the proper tags. I added two. If you think the matlab tag should be removed fine, but I don't think that it needs to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the permissions on just the MATLAB install.

If MATLAB is installed to `/home/*squirly*/MATLAB`, you could run the command below to make it accessible to all users.

`chmod -R a+rw /home/*squirly*/MATLAB`

If you do not own the directory you will need to prepend the command with `sudo`.

### BONUS:

If you want to allow **only some** users to use MATLAB.

Make a group called matlab:

`sudo groupadd matlab`

Make matlab the group owner of the matlab install:

`sudo chgrp -R matlab /home/*squirly*/MATLAB`

Allow the group to read/write to the matlab directory:

`sudo chmod -R g+rw /home/*squirly*/MATLAB`

Add users who will use matlab to the matlab group:

`sudo usermod -aG matlab *squirly*`

Comment: Thanks. But I want only one additional user(other than me) and not all users to be able to run matlab.

Comment: See the BONUS I added!